# Accessing slot inside nested component inside render() function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I am using Vue 3 and I have component with `render()` function something like this:

```
render() {
 return (
  <my-component>
   <div ref="cont" slot="cont">content</div>
  <my-component>
 )
}
```

And also inside `<my-component>` I also have `render()` function. And inside that function I want to access `slot="cont"`.

```
render() {
  console.log(this.$slots.cont());
}
```

It used to work with vue 2 but now I am migrating to vue 3 and it doesnt work. I just get `undefined` when console logging. What I am doing wrong? Why I cant access that slot?

Comment: Why are you using jsx with vue3?

Comment: Why not? It was not my decision to use it

Comment: It just makes it more complex. However, I've never worked with jsx in vue and barely saw someone using it.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test yet, but I think defining slot by `slot="slot_name"` is not working in JSX, using `vSlots` instead.

```
<my-component vSlots={{ cont: () => <div ref="cont">content</div>}}>
  <my-component>
```